# How to reset a form in AngularJS post submit from HTML only?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `form`. Post `submit`, if the `form` is *invalid*, the error props out below the `input` fields.

One can hide the `form` using Cancel button.

The form can be displayed again using 'Show Form' `button`.

*But the issue*: The old `form` **error** still persists.

How can one reset the form **without** setting the `ng-model` associated with it as the input fields should be empty during load?

The reset, I should be able to do it from `html` itself and **not** from the `controller`.

Code below:

```
<form novalidate name="form.customForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="model.name" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
          <span class="red" ng-show="(form.customForm.name.$touched && form.customForm.name.$error.required) || (form.customForm.name.$error.required &&     form.customForm.$submitted)">Name cannot be empty</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <label>Age</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="age" ng-model="model.age" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
          <span class="red" ng-show="(form.customForm.age.$touched && form.customForm.age.$error.required) || (form.customForm.age.$error.required &&     form.customForm.$submitted)">Age cannot be empty</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit(form.customForm.$valid);">
        Submit
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="isForm = false;">
        Cancel
      </button>

</form>
```

Refer the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/y8keb27f/).

Comment: Why don't you try ngMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you write the cancel button logic in the controller, are you sure you want to do it from the html itself?, you can use these statements to reset the form and fields.

```
form.customForm.$setPristine();
model = {};
form.customForm.$setUntouched();
```

[The updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8keb27f/3/)

Comment: thankx, exactly this i was looking for. I have tried with `form.customForm.$setPristine();` and `model = {};`, but didn't do the setting of `$setUntouched()`.

Answer (score 0):

what about just change the cancel button type to "reset" ?? It's the easiest solution

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" ng-click="isForm = false;">
     Cancel
</button>
```

Comment: But it does not work. When showing the form again, the error messages are still displayed
[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seza443/vbdj5h9e/1)

Comment: in this case just add a cancel() function with "$setPristine();" as
    $scope.cancel = function(isValid) {
    $scope.form.customForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.isForm = false;
     };

Comment: (cannot edit the previous) the cancel function should not have parameter

Answer (score 0):

On click on *Cancel* button, you could set 
`form.customForm.$submitted = false;`

This will hide the error messages.

Your cancel button becomes:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" 
  ng-click="isForm = false; form.customForm.$submitted = false;">
        Cancel
 </button>
```

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seza443/u3ahz6ax/)

Answer (score 0):

give the form a name:

```
<div ng-controller="BlaController as vm">
  <form name="vm.formOne">
  </form>
</div>
```

And in the controller do this: (thats how I made it work)

```
if (vm.formOne) {
  vm.formOne.$setPristine();
  vm.formOne.$setUntouched();
  vm.formOne.$commitViewValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.cancel = function(form){
   $scope.isForm = true;
   form.customForm.$submitted=false;
   form.customForm.name.$touched = false;
   form.customForm.age.$touched=false;
  }

 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="cancel(form)" ng-show="!isForm">
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y8keb27f/1/)

Or

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="isForm = true;
   form.customForm.$submitted=false;
   form.customForm.name.$touched = false;
   form.customForm.age.$touched=false;" ng-show="!isForm">
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y8keb27f/2/)